# How to run python script on Google Colab without changing directory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a working directory on Colab like this:

```
content/
|---work/
   |--- main.py
   |--- utils/
        |--- tool.py
```

In file `main.py`, I import file `tool.py`:

```
from utils import tool
```

When run a script on Colab, I use this command:

```
%%bash
cd work
python main.py
```

But in this way, I cannot see any output when the script is running, it has to stop to able to see it.

If I use this command, I can see the output:

```
!python /content/work/main.py
```

But there will be an error about `No such file or directory` if I import the `tool.py` file.

Do you guys know how to run the `main.py` script and can see the output during the execution?

Comment: You are trying to import from a different module which is present as a subset. Why not put the tool.py into the same directory as well? or else I'd suggest `%cd "/content/work/` and execute `!python "main.py"` that contains `from utils import tool` is the utils directory important?

Comment: @JimitVaghela the `utils` contains many files, I just give an example of my directory.

Comment: @JimitVaghela I use your suggestion `%cd /content/work` then `!python main.py` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Since it worked should I add that as an answer so it can be accepted by you and that should also help me in my reputation and others if they encounter such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import from a different module which is present as a subset. Why not put the tool.py into the same directory as well?
or else I'd suggest:

`%cd "/content/work/"` and execute `!python "main.py"` that contains `from utils import tool`